# Nginx Config load content through client proxy server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, real-ip

A user currently on their home network, 162.82.216.32, is trying to load our content through their proxy server, 192.231.231.16. When they load the site through their home network is displayed. Can anyone please advise if the above setup should handle that or if it should be altered?

This is the full block Nginx we currently have

```
set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
set_real_ip_from 172.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from 192.168.0.0/16;
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

Could anyone please advise what would be best in my scenario? Any help would be appreciated.